# What does "0x0030: 061c 0dd8 4745 5420 2f20 4854 5450 2f31" mean in tcpdump?

Tags: tcpdump

I am trying to learn `tcpdump`. I ran the following command:-

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -lnXs1600 host google.com and port 80
```

and got the following results:-

```
2:23:45.781779 IP 10.16.30.28.42957 > 173.194.36.65.http: Flags [S], seq 3301439566, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 212804497 ecr 0,nop,wscale 5], length 0
        0x0000:  4500 003c dbdf 4000 4006 64ad 0a10 1e1c  E..<..@.@.d.....
        0x0010:  adc2 2441 a7cd 0050 c4c7 f84e 0000 0000  ..$A...P...N....
        0x0020:  a002 16d0 a18e 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ................
        0x0030:  0caf 2391 0000 0000 0103 0305            ..#.........
12:23:45.782354 IP 173.194.36.65.http > 10.16.30.28.42957: Flags [S.], seq 3225093944, ack 3301439567, win 32768, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 0,nop,nop,TS val 102501848 ecr 212804497,sackOK,eol], length 0
        0x0000:  4500 0040 d258 4000 3f06 6f30 adc2 2441  E..@.X@.?.o0..$A
        0x0010:  0a10 1e1c 0050 a7cd c03b 0738 c4c7 f84f  .....P...;.8...O
        0x0020:  b012 8000 4be5 0000 0204 05b4 0103 0300  ....K...........
        0x0030:  0101 080a 061c 0dd8 0caf 2391 0402 0000  ..........#.....
12:23:45.782513 IP 10.16.30.28.42957 > 173.194.36.65.http: Flags [.], ack 1, win 183, options [nop,nop,TS val 212804497 ecr 102501848], length 0
        0x0000:  4500 0034 dbe0 4000 4006 64b4 0a10 1e1c  E..4..@.@.d.....
        0x0010:  adc2 2441 a7cd 0050 c4c7 f84f c03b 0739  ..$A...P...O.;.9
        0x0020:  8010 00b7 0af9 0000 0101 080a 0caf 2391  ..............#.
        0x0030:  061c 0dd8                                ....
12:23:45.783359 IP 10.16.30.28.42957 > 173.194.36.65.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:374, ack 1, win 183, options [nop,nop,TS val 212804498 ecr 102501848], length 373
        0x0000:  4500 01a9 dbe1 4000 4006 633e 0a10 1e1c  E.....@.@.c>....
        0x0010:  adc2 2441 a7cd 0050 c4c7 f84f c03b 0739  ..$A...P...O.;.9
        0x0020:  8018 00b7 2113 0000 0101 080a 0caf 2392  ....!.........#.
        0x0030:  061c 0dd8 4745 5420 2f20 4854 5450 2f31  ....GET./.HTTP/1
        0x0040:  2e31 0d0a 486f 7374 3a20 676f 6f67 6c65  .1..Host:.google
        0x0050:  2e63 6f6d 0d0a 5573 6572 2d41 6765 6e74  .com..User-Agent
        0x0060:  3a20 454c 696e 6b73 2f30 2e31 3270 7265  :.ELinks/0.12pre
        0x0070:  3520 2874 6578 746d 6f64 653b 204c 696e  5.(textmode;.Lin
        0x0080:  7578 3b20 3830 7832 342d 3229 0d0a 4163  ux;.80x24-2)..Ac
        0x0090:  6365 7074 3a20 2a2f 2a0d 0a41 6363 6570  cept:.*/*..Accep
        0x00a0:  742d 4c61 6e67 7561 6765 3a20 656e 0d0a  t-Language:.en..
        0x00b0:  436f 6e6e 6563 7469 6f6e 3a20 4b65 6570  Connection:.Keep
        0x00c0:  2d41 6c69 7665 0d0a 436f 6f6b 6965 3a20  -Alive..Cookie:.
        0x00d0:  5052 4546 3d49 443d 3066 3366 3864 3864  PREF=ID=0f3f8d8d
        0x00e0:  3538 6535 6534 6333 3a46 463d 303a 544d  58e5e4c3:FF=0:TM
        0x00f0:  3d31 3337 3234 3332 3939 373a 4c4d 3d31  =1372432997:LM=1
        0x0100:  3337 3234 3332 3939 373a 533d 4e7a 776e  372432997:S=Nzwn
        0x0110:  5a72 5a51 2d70 5f75 515a 666e 3b20 4e49  ZrZQ-p_uQZfn;.NI
        0x0120:  443d 3637 3d52 5a7a 3556 3072 5f4e 7849  D=67=RZz5V0r_NxI
        0x0130:  3470 3631 4875 354d 684a 7653 5235 5074  4p61Hu5MhJvSR5Pt
        0x0140:  6149 4a4f 6d72 6c32 7844 5f42 356c 4c78  aIJOmrl2xD_B5lLx
        0x0150:  6a65 756a 592d 4379 7562 4353 6b55 6a4c  jeujY-CyubCSkUjL
        0x0160:  656f 5a49 5757 5334 5f78 2d6d 5551 6e6e  eoZIWWS4_x-mUQnn
        0x0170:  3831 5067 586a 426e 7771 386f 365a 3775  81PgXjBnwq8o6Z7u
        0x0180:  3953 6459 776e 5453 7155 706e 5946 7842  9SdYwnTSqUpnYFxB
        0x0190:  347a 795a 3036 6e75 6355 5f47 582d 4e78  4zyZ06nucU_GX-Nx
        0x01a0:  475f 6544 310d 0a0d 0a                   G_eD1....
```

I want to know what does `0x0030:  061c 0dd8 4745 5420 2f20 4854 5450 2f31`
stand for in the line `0x0030:  061c 0dd8 4745 5420 2f20 4854 5450 2f31  ....GET./.HTTP/1`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `0x0030: 061c 0dd8 4745 5420 2f20 4854 5450 2f31 stands for in the line 0x0030: 061c 0dd8 4745 5420 2f20 4854 5450 2f31`

This is a hexadecimal representation of data in the packet starting from byte number `0x0030` or `48`.  `06` is byte 48, `1c` is byte 49 and so on.

> `....GET./.HTTP/1`

is a text representation of the same payload string as above.

Comment: Note the "." characters in the text representation are typically placeholders for byte values that do not have a corresponding printable character associated with it.

Comment: +1, i wasn't aware of the text representation. I was trying to decode the hexadecimal to ascii and wasn't getting the correct information.  I used `hex to text` converter `http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx` and got the same result. Thank you !!

Comment: @Richm, +1 for this extra information.